# Using links to scroll an article without closing the modal

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it so that when you click on a link, it scrolls down to the next part. It seems to scroll just fine, but it always closes when I click on a link. Is there any way to work around this?

```css
.modalDialog {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'gothic' !important;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
  width: 90%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  top: 12px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: solid #2E51A2 2px;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  color: #999;
}

.close {
  background: #2E51A2;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover {
  color: #000;
}

#content {
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
  font-family: 'gothic' !important;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 396px;
  border: 2px solid #2E51A2;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

#description {
  width: 100%;
  height: 396px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#contentGuide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 396px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.contentLink {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border-left: 2px solid #2E51A2;
  border-right: 2px solid #2E51A2;
  border-top: 2px solid #2E51A2;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  color: #999;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  right: 4px;
  font-size: 16pt;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

.contentLink:active {
  background-color: #2E51A2;
}

#linkContain {
  width: 60%;
  height: 54px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
  <div> <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <div id="linkContain">
      <a href="#description" class="contentLink">About</a><a href="#contentGuide" class="contentLink">Content Guide</a>
    </div>
    <article id="content">
      <article id="description">
        Content 1
      </article>

      <article id="contentGuide">
        Content 2
      </article>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this working snippet , this is what you need i think

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  activaTab('aaa');
});

function activaTab(tab){
  $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};
```

```css
.modalDialog {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: 'gothic' !important;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
 z-index: 99999;
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.modalDialog:target {
 opacity:1;
 pointer-events: auto;
}

.modalDialog > div {
 width: 90%;
 height: 600px;
 position: relative;
 top: 12px;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: solid #2E51A2 2px;
 background-color: #1d1d1d;
 color: #999;
}

.close {
 background: #2E51A2;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -12px;
 text-align: center;
 top: -10px;
 width: 24px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-border-radius: 12px;
 border-radius: 12px;
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}

.close:hover {
 color: #000;
}

#tabs {
 width: 60%;
 float: right;
 font-family: 'gothic' !important;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 height: 396px;
 border: 2px solid #2E51A2;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

#description {
 width: 100%;
 height: 396px;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

#contentGuide {
 width: 100%;
 height: 396px;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

.contentLink {
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 50px;
 border-left: 2px solid #2E51A2;
 border-right: 2px solid #2E51A2;
 border-top: 2px solid #2E51A2;
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #1d1d1d;
 color: #999;
 position: relative;
 top: 2px;
 right: 4px;
 font-size: 16pt;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
}

.contentLink:active {
 background-color: #2E51A2;
}

#linkContain {
 width: 60%;
 height: 54px;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>
 
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
 <div> <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
  <div id="linkContain">
   <a href="#description" class="contentLink" data-toggle="tab">About</a>
            <a href="#contentGuide" class="contentLink" data-toggle="tab">Content Guide</a>
  </div>
  <article class="tab-content" id="tabs">
   <article class="tab-pane" id="description">
    Content 1
   </article>
    
   <article class="tab-pane" id="contentGuide">
    Content 2
   </article>
  </article>
        </div>
</div>


<!-- /.outer --> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```